# Can't open Minecraft with java

Tags: java, minecraft

I know this has been asked here before, but none of the solutions have worked for me. I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 on my system and I installed Open Java 7 and I downloaded Minecraft. I right clicked Minecraft went to properties and set it as an executable and then went to open with and Java is no where to be found in the list. I made a new Java desktop file in /usr/share/applications and now when I go to the list Java is there and I set Minecraft to open with it by default but when I open it nothing at all happens. Now how am I supposed to get Minecraft to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terminal type `java -jar /path/to/your/minecraft.jar`, or you can run this [Minecraft launcher](http://devio.us/~clorow/minecraft_deb.cgi). I have used it myself and will vouch for its effectiveness. It even will give you a nice menu icon.

Comment: The Minecraft Launcher fixed the issue with opening Minecraft. However Java still does not show in the app list of the contextual menu. Thank you thought ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Try going here http://modifyubuntu.com/ and search for Minecraft in the bar.
Might help you, it's worth a try